# Aplications sharing same screen space (WPF)

Tags: wpf

I'll try to summarize my problem. I have two applications developed in WPF, initially they were a single application, but I splitted them because both have intensive UI updates. Both applications share a common area of ​​the screen, and my target is to merge the applications but only visually.

The old environment is the drawing with the "OLD" label. I was able to achieve that, simply starting the App2 with the Topmost attribute, and therefore visually for the user was as if they were the same application.

[image]

In the new environment I have an user control (the green box) owned by the App1, and I have problems merging them. Is it possible to get it?

My current solution is to put the "green box" user control in the App2 and comunicate both applications via WCF for messaging but, is there any way to get the visual effect I want while keeping the "green box" user control in the App1?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're overcomplicating everything. Simply have a single application (.Exe file) and have many `Dispatcher` threads if you need independence of UI processing between separate Windows. In other words, each of your Windows can have it's own Dispatcher and there's no need for WCF or anything like that.  Airspace issues will appear, but it's much easier when your Windows "see" each other because they're part of the same project / assembly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried to have multiple UI threads following this tutorial: http://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/   But when I do that in my application, all is slowed. My main issue is that one application is showing four  high quality videos.